# React Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am getting an error for the line that contains "this.props.isCompleted?" saying that the 'this' is an unexpected keyword and i dont understand why because i am using a class component. This is actually an old project i worked on last year and it was working fine but today is my first day looking at it again and im not sure why i am getting that error now.

```
  import React from "react";

  class Todo extends React.Component {
    state = {
       checked: false
      };

 handleCheck = () => {
//allows you to check and uncheck
this.setState({
  checked: !this.state.checked
  });
};

handleClick = () => {
   this.props.handlecompletedList({
   title: this.props.title
 });
};

handleDeleteTask = () => {
  this.props.deleteTask(this.props);
  };

 render() {
   const { title } = this.props;
   let current_date = new Date();
   let formatted_date =
   current_date.getMonth() +
   1 +
   "/" +
   current_date.getDate() +
   "/" +
  current_date.getFullYear();

return (
  
  {
     this.props.isCompleted?

  <div>

  {title}

  </div>

  :
  
  
  <div className="ui checked checkbox">  
     <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onChange={this.handleCheck}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
    
    <label
      style={{
        textDecorationLine: this.state.checked ? "line-through" : "none",
        textDecorationStyle: "solid",
        textDecorationColor: "red"
      }}
    >
      {title}
    </label>
    <button
      onClick={this.handleDeleteTask}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "indigo",
        color: "white",
        position: "absolute",
        right: "-50px",
        top: "-5px"
      }}
      className="mini ui button"
    >
      {" "}
      X{" "}
    </button>
    <p
      style={{
        fontFamily: "cursive",
        color: "purple",
        position: "absolute",
        right: "-115px",
        top: "0px"
      }}
    >
      {formatted_date}
    </p>
  </div>
}




  );
 }
 }
 export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSX syntax is not valid.

It needs to be at least surrounded by a `<></>` tag to let react recognize your JS expressions in the curly braces.

Check out the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) to see how JSX actually works.

```
return (
    <>
        {this.props.isCompleted ?
            <div> {title} </div>
            :
            <div>something else</div>
        }
    </>
);
```

Note that `<></>` is a shorthand for [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Alternatively, you can also just do the branching with vanilla JS by skipping the JSX special embedded JS.

```
return (
    this.props.isCompleted ?
        <div> {title} </div>
        :
        <div>something else</div>
);
```

Comment: thanks alot ive never seen that symbol before, but its been almost 2 years since ive used react so i wonder if its something new

Comment: It looks like they added it in [2017](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `this` in the HTML. You only use that in methods

```
return ( { props.isCompleted ?
<div>
  {title}
</div>
:
<div className="ui checked checkbox"></div>
});
```